# getting oauth_problem=signature_invalid when exchanging LinkedIn JSAPI token for OAuth token

Tags: linkedin-api

I am following linked in documentation to exchange a JSAPI token for a OAuth 1.0a token. (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens)

**I got the following error during the exchange:**

oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_problem_advice=com.linkedin.security.auth.pub.LoginDeniedInvalidAuthTokenException%20while%20obtaining%20request%20token%20for%20%3APOST%26https%253A%252F%252Fapi.linkedin.com%252Fuas%252Foauth%252FaccessToken%26oauth_consumer_key%253D751oglji2r3e9e%2526oauth_nonce%253D1422656976%2526oauth_signature_method%253DHMAC-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1422656976654%2526oauth_version%253D1.0%2526xoauth_oauth2_access_token%253DzdLOTq4fVfiSBS4WP_FkEgL942vbUkpsH4gH%0ACONN%3AO%7C4245561%7C3241891%7C7315878%7C4307091%7C%2A02%3A1422656976%3AgwtcYNp1ZiULkjvCXvnbOWM2fps%253D

I used the the LinkedIn OAuth test console to test my signature algorithm
(https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console)
and I confirmed that I am constructing the same base_string and got the same signature as the test-console.

However I am still getting the signature_invalid error which suggest that I might be constructing the HTTP POST request incorrectly.

**This is what my request looks like:**

POST /uas/oauth/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="751oglji2r3e9e", oauth_nonce="1422654439", oauth_signature="vif9BS8MFNdjTWCagrs%252Fn8gNa1Y%253D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1422654439035", oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_71
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: close
Content-Length: 63

xoauth_oauth2_access_token=AykDWuciDtpUQ_2tY4y3sKOOqOD6JXUSwuZR

**I url encoded my signature because this is what some of the other post suggest.  Is this the right way?**

The error message from LinkedIn does not make it clear as to why the signature is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Re-examining the signature in the Authorization header, it appear that I made the mistake of URL encoding the signature twice when putting it in the Authorization header.

Once I fix this I was able to obtain the access token.